# Cakephp: My LIKE function in my query doesn't work

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

Im working on a query that uses a variable `$name` to get only **one** result from the database.

My Query looks like this.

```
$this->Project->find('first', array('Project.name LIKE' => '%$name%'));
```

Instead of returning the right data it returns the first data from the database.

I have a self made query that works, but i want it to have it like a Cake query

```
$this->Project->query("SELECT * FROM projects WHERE name LIKE '%$name%'");
```

The most will say why dont you use `findByName`? Because the variable `$name` is not exactly the same as the name in the database.

Can somebody please help me with this? I have read the documents of cakePHP, but i can't figure out what im doing wrong. [Cake Retrieving Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The find syntax should be :

```
$this->Project->find('first', array('conditions' => array('Project.name LIKE' => "%$name%")));
```

Comment: Sorry - the final string needs to be either double quotes or a concatenation because of your variable

Comment: Yes thank you very much, after the fix with the double quotes it worked!